# Pandas/Python: How to find number of unique values in column A (that is grouped by), where a value in column B does not exist in column C

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with the following column names `account_id`, `viewed_job_id` and `posted_job_id`.

Each row is unique, but there are multiple `account_id` of the same value in multiple rows.

I want to find the number of unique `account_id` that satisfies the condition that there exist at least one `viewed_job_id` for that account that isn't in `posted_job_id`.

Here is an example:

| account_id | viewed_job_id | posted_job_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_1 | j_1 | j_2 |
| a_1 | j_2 | j_1 |
| a_2 | j_1 | j_4 |
| a_2 | j_3 | j_1 |
| a_3 | j_2 | j_3 |
| a_3 | j_3 | j_3 |

The end result will show that `a_2` and `a_3` satisfy this condition and will return 2.

I am thinking there will need a `group_by('account_id')` prior to checking whether `viewed_job_id` does not exists in `posted_job_id`, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df1=df.groupby("account_id",as_index=False).agg(list)
df1['no_of_jobs']=df1.apply(lambda x:len([i for i in x.viewed_job_id if i not in x.posted_job_id]),axis=1)
```

output:

```
print(df1[['account_id','no_of_jobs']])

  account_id  no_of_jobs
0        a_1           0
1        a_2           1
2        a_3           1

unique_jobs=df1['no_of_jobs'].sum()
print(unique_jobs)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this solution from ChatGPT works:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'account_id': ['a_1', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'a_2', 'a_3', 'a_3'],
    'viewed_job_id': ['j_1', 'j_2', 'j_1', 'j_3', 'j_2', 'j_3'],
    'posted_job_id': ['j_2', 'j_1', 'j_4', 'j_1', 'j_3', 'j_3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Step 1: Group by 'account_id' and check if there's at least one 'viewed_job_id' not in 'posted_job_id'
def has_unposted_jobs(group):
    return ~group['viewed_job_id'].isin(group['posted_job_id']).all()

filtered_groups = df.groupby('account_id').filter(has_unposted_jobs)

# Step 2: Get the number of unique 'account_id' that satisfy the condition
unique_accounts = filtered_groups['account_id'].nunique()

print(unique_accounts)  # Output: 2
```